# CSS + IE 6 = Image caching and padding

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have a web page. This web page looks correct in IE 7, 8 FF 2, 3, 3.5 Safari 3, 4 Opera 9, 10 and Chrome. Essentially everything except IE 6.

The layout even looks fine. There are seemingly two things that are not showing properly.

1. Each list item has a gray vertical line in it. This line moves if I adjust my padding value. I do not want the gray vertical line. This line only appears in IE 6.
2. I have a list that drops down. When this list appears the first time, the background-images appear. However, on subsequent attempts, the image does not appear. Once again, this is only on IE 6.

Here is the general code I am using. I have moved the styles inline for the sake of readability.

```
<div id="theDiv" style="height:29px; width: 100%; background-image: url('./Images/bg.jpg');position:absolute; top:10px;">
  <ul style="list-style-type:none; position:relative; display:inline;">
    <li style="position:relative; display:inline; background-image: url('./Images/bg2.jpg'); padding:5px 6px;">Item 1</li>
    <li style="position:relative; display:inline; background-image: url('./Images/bg2.jpg'); padding:5px 6px;">Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I over come these silly issues? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an online test page that we can see?

Comment: Yes, being able to see this in action would be much better.  Could that vertical line maybe be part of the background image and the image may just need to be repositioned?  Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Does it help problem 2 if you use the full background-image urls instead?  I have heard that IE6 can have problems calling images within CSS depending on the directory they are stored in.

Otherwise, I agree with Ionut and Slevin - Either posting the code in its entirety or linking to the page at question would be a lot more helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this kind of problems depend on the IE6 border bug. See for example this:

http://www.simple-site.eu/test-lab/ie-bugs/ie6-border-bug.html

The grey line is probably due to some div not fully covering the background.

A screenshot woul be helpful for a useful answer, since I don't have IE6.